# How do I change the colour of the white border when using RatioResolutionPolicy in AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am testing out different resolutions on my dark colour themed game.  And I have noticed AndEngine will leave white borders when using RatioResolutionPolicy.  How can I change the colour of this border to make my game appear more easy to the eye?

```
        final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,
            CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera).setNeedsSound(true);
```

Comment: Ok please clarify this on which thing it leaves that white border ?

Comment: When my phone resolution is not equal in proportion to my camera width and height, AndEngine will compensate depending on your ResolutionPolicy, in my case by leaving a border around the visible region for the app.  Unfortunately this border is white and I would like to know how to change it to black.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately I have the same problem, but only when I updated my Android SDK, so maybe that was the problem anyway, but the solution to your problem and it was for mine, it's to go to `res/values/styles.xml` and edit this line:

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"
```

Change to `Theme.Black`.

Do the same thing for all `styles.xml` files, i.e. inside the folders `res/values-v11` and `res/values-v14`.

That should work, now the borders are no longer white.

Comment: I also had to change the value in `values-v14/styles` for anyone looking for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is over a year late, but the correct way is to add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

to your activity(every activity) in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the border of sprites than there is a border that appears around sprites,when using texture packer to create sprites. So if you make a 50x50 size sprite it comes into the app as a 52x52 sized sprite.

**SOLUTION :**

*The problem was solved by setting extrude to at least 1.*

I think this might be your case.

Thanks.

Comment: no sorry I mean when my phone resolution is not equal in proportion to my camera width and height, AndEngine will compensate depending on your ResolutionPolicy, in my case by leaving a border around the visible region for the app.  Unfortunately this border is white and I would like to know how to change it to black.